# Rip and transcode using avconv

Tags: transcoding, avconv

I converted a video tape to DVD with an old converter,
then copied the DVD to my linux mint system to get a directory:

```
$ /bin/ls -s
     12 VIDEO_TS.BUP
     12 VIDEO_TS.IFO
     56 VIDEO_TS.VOB
     76 VTS_01_0.BUP
     76 VTS_01_0.IFO
1048548 VTS_01_1.VOB
1048548 VTS_01_2.VOB
1048548 VTS_01_3.VOB
1020164 VTS_01_4.VOB
```

I run linux mint and want to use avconv to convert this to something
playable on my wife's macbook.  But avconv gives error messages ...

```
$ avconv -v info  -i VTS_01_1.VOB -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 800k -g 300 -bf 2 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k tempa.mp4

avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
VTS_01_1.VOB: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I think the files are OK, since I can play this directory using
`vlc .`

Then vlc shows a menu screen with one possible option, "01", and when
I click that option I can view about 1 hour of video.

How can I convert the files in this directory to something
a macbook could play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a better way.  On the Linux side I used
handbrake to rip the DVD files to get .mkv files.

Then on the Mac OS X side, I found the installed quicktime
was lame, and wouldn't play .avi or .mkv files.  So I
installed VLC, http://www.videolan.org/index.html,
and it plays the .mkv files well.